# Pi to Pi communication using Python

Tags: python, networking

I started a project where i want 2 Pis to exchange codes (numerical only) and i have read how it is possible with a additional server but can it be done without?

specific usecase:

RPI1 detects a value and sends it to RPI2 which then triggers a PIN
It will be a RPI3/4 and a zero (maybe multiple but one is even to complicated for me now)
Every help is appreciated

Comment: UART, SPI, (W)LAN, take your pick

Comment: ...TCP, UDP... But note that questions about network programming in python belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) or [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to run a script on one Pi which controls its own GPIO (if desired) as well as the GPIO on other networked Pis (if desired).